# Uncaught (in promise) Error: invalid address

Tags: javascript, solidity, smartcontracts

how to fix this error when i call a smart contract function?

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: invalid address (argument="address", value={"from":"0xaD1D30B476C195C23ef4CC9b7A3c53E7423B7690"}, code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=address/5.0.5) (argument="index", value={"from":"0xaD1D30B476C195C23ef4CC9b7A3c53E7423B7690"}, code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=abi/5.0.7)
```

it's my code:

```
enter: async function() {
    App.contracts["MyContract"].deployed().then(async(instance) =>{
      var a = web3.eth.getAccounts();
      let ticketsForPlayers  = await instance.getTicketsForPlayers({from: App.account});
      console.log(ticketsForPlayers);
    });
  }
```

Comment: Please check this link: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/19524/invalid-address-error-when-interacting-with-a-smart-contract-with-metamask

Comment: wrap await code in try/catch block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

##### The Problem

The error shows that you didn't set the `address` property correctly, it's may be the issue with your `solidity` implementation and it's not related to javascript snippet, as mentioned in the comments, you can ask about it on related sites, but there are some points with the above snippet that may help you.
you are mixing two different implementations in `enter` method to handle a promise which is clearly incorrect and leads to the issues.

##### The Points

use `async/await` with `try/catch` block. more on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await#adding_error_handling) documentation:

```
enter: async function () {
  try {
    const instance = await App.contracts["MyContract"].deployed()
    
    const properNameForVariable = web3.eth.getAccounts();

    const ticketsForPlayers = await instance.getTicketsForPlayers({from: App.account})

    console.log(ticketsForPlayers)
  } catch (error) {
    // do a proper action on failure cases
  }
}
```

Now, if there are errors in your async actions, it catches by `catch` block, you may also use `console.error(error)` or `console.warn(error)` in the catch block to see the exception and stack traces.

**Note:** using this approach with try/catch will ensure the application continues to work even after exceptions and errors.

Comment: yes, right! but i've got the same error in catch block, why?  it's a solidity problem?

Comment: maybe, since you can log the error properly and use it to debug your application. but using try/catch block will help you to catch the errors. in this way, exceptions or errors can't cause you to crash your application and stop working. @Mattia

Comment: As a suggestion, you can ask about the error in related forums (mentioned in the comments) @Mattia

Comment: @Mattia I've updated my answer with some clarification about the issue and solution since my answer is not the exact thing you need, you may accept or upvote it after checking it again, with the best regards

Answer (score 0):

using an old version of web3 for a tutorial web3@0.20.6 and Firefox 100.0.1

this was what I added to react to get resolve the error

web3.eth.defaultAccount = web3.eth.accounts[0]